# How to set wall texture in osmbuilding-leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, 3d-model, building

I'm working with osmbuilding-leaflet to render 3D features on map but there is a problem. After rendering features wall of buildings doesn't have texture. But in the basic osmbuilding library wall textures are shown

this image is for osmbuilding library :

[image]

and this image is for osmbuilding-leaflet library :

[image]

How can solve this problem ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some info about osmbuilding-leaflet.